# Extend ArrayAdapter and Activity in one class?

Tags: android, class

I have a small but very unpractical problem :). I am extending the ArrayAdapter class for my CustomArrayAdapter, but I now also want to start a new Activity in this class. The thing is, I wanted to extend it but it's not accepting it. Google also states it is just not possible in android, and that I must extend my application. Only thing, how do I call the method then? Object.startActivity ??

Thanks!

Comment: If you define CustomArrayAdapterinside within your activity, you can call ClassnameOfActivity.this.startActivity();

Comment: @Jack If you need to display items in the next activity that belongs to a particular level, you can add one more column in the database called `item_level` which will identify the level the each item(row) belongs to.
And you can pass the level number to the next activity and then display the items of the passed level.

You can set the level number for each item of ListView using the `setTag()` method and retrieve the level number of the clicked item using the `getTag()` method of `View` class.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to implement is [Multiple Inheritance](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-07/02-qa-0719-multinheritance.html) and the Java language does not support this.

You can try some thing like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
        .....
        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        .....
    }

    class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        // your adapter implementation.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @mrres1 It's not mandatory to extend ListActivity and infact it's a user's choice. I can have a ListView in my `your_activity_layout.xml` and I can refer to it using `findViewById` method.

Comment: As I said earlier, it not mandatory to extend `ListActivity` for using `ListView`. It's upon how user/developer want to manage `ListView` and it's adapters.
`ListActivity` provides some shortcuts methods like `onListItemClick()`, `setListAdapter()` and we need to call(android:id) `ListView` as `@android:id/list` in corresponding layout xml file. What if in case I need to display two ListViews in activity using different adapters? So how will I manage this case using `ListActivity`?

Comment: @mrres1 Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html for why did Android create ListActivity.

Comment: I think you are not getting what I am trying to say. If you read my comments with open eyes you'll find that I NEVER SAID NOT TO USE ListView. The link in my previous comment was an answer to your question "Why did Android create the ListActivity class?" By the way what about this : What if in case I need to display two ListViews in activity using different adapters? So how will I manage this case using ListActivity?

  And nothing personal!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't start an Activity from an ArrayAdapter.
When do you want to start it ? 
You can handle a click on an item of the list by setting an ItemClickListener on the GroupView you are using.

```
ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
view.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), array));
view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    startActivity(intent);

}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I tried this to do it like this:

```
CustomArrayAdapter myAdapter= new CustomArrayAdapter(this, questions);
gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            myDbHelper.close();
            Intent i = new Intent("com.bgdroid.quizapp.ANSWER");
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
});
```

The problem here: the info on the views comes from a database entry. I cannot call v.getId() and get the database info in the next Activity with this id because there are many items (60, so id 1 to 60) but displayed per level. (id 1-20 is level 1, id 20-40 is level 2,...)

By typing this, I realize now that I do can get the id, pass it to the next activity and perform like: v.getItem() + (itemsPerLevel * (currentLevel - 1)) .

You guys think this is the best solution? Sorry for the quite difficult explanation :)